# Gridview update automatically rounds decimal value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

When I update a gridview row, the decimal value automatically rounds. Suppose the price value in the edit textbox is 1.25, then it becomes 1 etc. The datatype in sql table is numeric(18,2). Please help me to fix the problem.

```
enter code here
protected void RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox MPrice = ((TextBox)GridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtPrice"));        
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = decimal.Parse(MPrice.Text);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

aspx:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price", "{0:n2}") %>'>    </asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPrice" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPrice" ErrorMessage="*" MaximumValue="99999" MinimumValue=".01" Type="Double"></asp:RangeValidator>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: have u tried to debug?

Comment: debug gives the correct value entered in the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Textbox formatting from `Text='<%# Bind("Price", "{0:n2}") %>` to `Text='<%# Bind("Price", "{0:n}") %>`

**UPDATE:** Looks like Sql server has to do something with auto rounding of decimals.`Try changing datatype from decimal(18,2) to float in database.` [Here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1204718.aspx/1)'s a discussion. [Here](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10028341/how-to-disable-autmatic-round-of-of-a-decimal-number.aspx)'s another one. Hope it helps.

Comment: Even after removing the format, the result is same. If the value in the table is 0.25(eg) it displays in the gridview correctly but update rounds automatically.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and watch the value of `decimal.Parse(MPrice.Text)`

Comment: It tried 2.25 in the textbox and getting the same value at breakpoint but saved as 2.0 in the table.

Comment: I tried float, numeric and money but the result is same. I have used numeric (18,2) in another table and updating from another gridview in another page without any problems with the datatype.